# How can i apply tuple to my code so I can get an output "{('a', 'x'))"?

Tags: python

Below is my code. Its written for when a user enters 2 text files, it pairs lines from the text files together.

```
#User enters text file names
user_input = input("Enter First Text file: ")
user_input2 = input("Enter Second Text file: ")

#Opens the inputted text files
File = open(user_input, "r")
Text1 = File.read().splitlines()

File2 = open(user_input, "r")
Text2 = File2.read().splitlines()

PairedFiles = set()
for r in Text1[0].split(): 
    for s in Text2[0].split(): 
        PairedFiles.add(r + s) 
print(PairedFiles)
```

These are examples text files that would be used in relation to the above code:

**Text File #1:**

```
a
```

**Text File #2:**

```
x
```

The output of this is:

```
{'ax'}
```

The output I'm wanting is:

```
{('a', 'x'))
```

Its been said that the above output happens when using tuples. How would I apply tuple to get the above desired output of `{('a', 'x'))`?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your desired output isn't even valid in Python. You've repeated it twice, so it's not a typo. Why would you even want that, if it was `{('a', 'x')}`? That looks like you want JSON

Comment: @roganjosh How can you be sure it's not a typo? He probably just copied the first string, I know I would have.

Comment: @gblomqvist then you should take more effort over writing posts. We're not here to guess at badly-written posts. If people want help, they need to review their posts properly; so it escaped their review of their own question twice. EDIT: they did it thrice

Comment: @roganjosh Isn't it pretty obvious what was meant? And even if it wasn't, you could always ask for clarification/suggest an edit.

Comment: @gblomqvist I could just edit it, I don't need to suggest it. But that would be the _wrong_ thing to do here (please don't suggest it). I highlighted the issue in my first post; the OP should be perfectly aware of the issue and can edit it out. It's not for _any_ of us to make changes like that. This might be a trivial example, but I've seen it cause all sorts of issues when people take it upon themselves to make such changes

Comment: @roganjosh it looks perfectly valid python to me.

Comment: @quamrana as a string, sure. How do you propose parsing it when reading it in?

Comment: Ok, now I’m confused. I thought that the set containing a tuple was the output.

Comment: @quamrana look again at `{('a', 'x'))`. That is not a set because there is no closing `}` but instead a `)`. It's repeated 3 times; in the question title and twice in the question (which was edited and I rolled it back, and the edit didn't even fix the title)

Comment: Ok, I missed that. Point taken. I will be voting to close soon given no feedback from the OP. (although all the clues are there in the question: creating a set in the code and mentioning tuples.)

Comment: @quamrana I agree with you fully that the clues are there, but I've seen so many things derailed by people making assumptions like these. It's for the OP to fix. In a broader context, I can't think of a single reason why you'd want to store this in a text file, so I don't think the Q/A is of any use to anyone else

Comment: @quamrana and it's just been edited and none of them were "corrected" by the OP :/

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 'a' + 'x'   # adding two strings
'ax'
>>> ('a', 'x')  # forming a tuple of two strings
('a', 'x')
```

Change this:

```
PairedFiles.add(r + s)
```

to this:

```
PairedFiles.add((r, s))
```